# não consigo comparar datas

Tags: php, mysql

Alguém pode me dizer o que está acontecendo nesse código?
A primeira querie funciona porém ela não entra na condição dentro do for.
A Segunda funciona e se comporta normal, sem problemas com essa.
O caso é que nunca vi isso antes minha comparação dentro do for ela nunca fica verdadeira mesmo ambas tendo o mesmo comprimento e sendo do mesmo tipo.

segue o código:

```js
public function getDias($dia){
    $sql=$this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM agendamento WHERE dia = '$dia'");
    // $sql=$this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM agendamento");
    $horaBD = array(8=>"1");
    $responseArr = [];
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){     
      array_push($horaBD,date("H:i",strtotime($row['horario'])));
    }

    for ($i=9; $i <= 18; $i++) {
      $horaFor = ($i<10) ? "0".$i.":00" : $i.":00";
      if ($horaFor == @$horaBD[$i]) continue;//aqui eu substitui por and para funcionar do jeito esperado
      else array_push($responseArr,$horaFor);
    }
    echo "<br>". json_encode($responseArr);

  }
```

Esqueci de mencionar que estou usando a versão 7.2 do php não sei se isso importa.

como segerido por LipESprY:

```js
horaFor : 09:00   horaDB: 10:00
horaFor : 10:00   horaDB: 11:00
horaFor : 11:00   horaDB: 15:00
horaFor : 12:00   horaDB: 11:00
horaFor : 13:00   horaDB: 15:00
```

Comment: Tente rodar um `var_dump()` nas duas variáveis e comparar visualmente as variáveis...

Comment: Valeu consegui ver o que eu estava fazendo de  errado agora tou pensando numa solução. Vou atualizar o post para ficar mais visivel.

Comment: @LipESprY Eu consegui fazer a compararação descobri o que era Valeu pela dica do var_dump().

Comment: Fmz, Bro! Agora responda sua pergunta e aceite como solução.

Comment: @LipESprY Eu mesmo responder minha pergunta? pode isso Arnaldo? kkkk

Comment: Isso é o certo. Recomendações da comunidade. Evita que sua pergunta fique perambulando sem solução...

Comment: Rapaz. Não seria mais simples selecionar os horários entre 9 e 18 horas direto na query. Tá uma baderna seu código.
SELECT * FROM agendamento WHERE dia = '$dia' AND TIME(horario) BETWEEN '12:00:00' AND '18:00:00'

Comment: @MarcosXavier Acho que não funcionaria pois eu preciso que os horários que já estejam agendados entre 12:00 e 18:00 sejam subtraido do array final mostrando apenas os horarios disponiveis, Valeu pela dica.
reconheço que meu código está bagunçado, :) , mas eu estou tentando melhorar, antes nem fazia o código orientado a objetos kkkk,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
public function getDias($dia,$hralmoco=12,$intervalo=1){

    $dia = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($dia));
    $sql=$this->conn->query("SELECT * FROM agendamento WHERE dia = '$dia'");
    $horaBD = array(8=>"1");
    $horaFor = array(8=>"1");
    $responseArr=array();
    while($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
      array_push($horaBD,date("H:i",strtotime($row['horario'])));
    }
    for($i=9;$i<=18;$i++){
      if($i >= $hralmoco && $i < $hralmoco+$intervalo) continue;

      ($i<10) ? array_push($horaFor,("0".$i.":00")):array_push($horaFor,($i.":00"));
    }
    unset($horaBD[8],$horaFor[8]);
    //essa foi a solução encontrada pois eu tinha que entrar no array horaBD
    //para apagar o indice em que o valor do Array HoraFor fosse igual a horaBD
    // não sei deu para entender bem :(

    //Solução
    foreach($horaBD as $key => $value){
      for ($i=9; $i < 19; $i++) {
        if($value == @$horaFor[$i]) {
          unset($horaFor[$i]);
        }
      }
    }
     //Solução
    forEach($horaFor as $key=>$value){
      array_push($responseArr);
    }

    echo json_encode($responseArr);
  }
```

Depois de executado o Código acima devolvem esses arrays o $responseArr é subtraçao do $horaDB e $horaFor onde ele devolve apenas a diferença entre eles

array $horaBD{

```
 [9] => 10:00
[10] => 11:00
[11] => 15:00
[12] => 11:00
[13] => 15:00
```

}

array $horaFor{

```
 [9] => 09:00
[10] => 10:00
[11] => 11:00
[12] => 13:00
[13] => 14:00
[14] => 15:00
[15] => 16:00
[16] => 17:00
[17] => 18:00
```

}

$responseArr={

```
[0] => 09:00
[1] => 13:00
[2] => 14:00
[3] => 16:00
[4] => 17:00
[5] => 18:00
```

}

O problema foi que antes meu for estava sendo comparado assim:

```js
for ($i=9; $i <= 18; $i++) {
      $horaFor = ($i<10) ? "0".$i.":00" : $i.":00";
      if ($horaFor == @$horaBD[$i]) continue;//aqui eu substitui por and para funcionar do jeito esperado
      else array_push($responseArr,$horaFor);
    }
```

e isso estava gerando o seguinte código:

```js
horaFor : 09:00   horaDB: 10:00
horaFor : 10:00   horaDB: 11:00
horaFor : 11:00   horaDB: 15:00
horaFor : 12:00   horaDB: 11:00
horaFor : 13:00   horaDB: 15:00
```

ou seja eu não estava comparando todos o intervalo valores, dentro de $horaBD com o $horaFor, estava apenas com comparado-os diretamente,
assim :

```js
$horaFor = 10;
$horaDB = 12;
if($horaDB == $horaFor) continue;
```

Para resolver isso eu use atualizei bloco do código :

```js
foreach($horaBD as $key => $value){
      for ($i=9; $i < 19; $i++) {
        if($value == @$horaFor[$i]) {
          unset($horaFor[$i]);
        }
      }
    }
```

Agora ele lê todo o invervalo de valores dentro de $horaDB e caso haja alguma correspondência ele elimina do array $responseArr;

Comment: Faltou explicar "qual foi a solução" e marcar a resposta como solução. ;)

Comment: @LipESprY atualizei a resposta, acho que agora dá para entender o que eu tava tentando fazer =), Desculpa acho que não formulei a pergunta de uma maneira entendível .

Comment: Que luta, heim! kkkk

Comment: @LipESprY Valeu pela ajuda nem tava pensava no var_dump() na hora, tava quase desistindo.

Comment: Depois experimente `print_r($variavel);`. Tem efeito semelhante, mas é mais compreensível. Digamos que faz a mesma coisa, sem dizer o tipo de cada ramificação da variável/vetor...

Comment: @LipESprY Realmente ajuda muito esse print_r, valeu pelas dicas.